# Use Gulp to copy all bower package font files to build directory

Tags: gulp

I am using the following Gulp task to copy required fonts from the Font Awesome Bower package, this works fine and outputs files like so:

App > Build > Fonts > Font Files

```
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
   gulp.src('./bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./fonts'));
});
```

**I am trying to refactor this task so that it moves the fonts from any bower package (Bootstrap, for example) using the ** wildcard.**

```
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
   gulp.src('./bower_components/**/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./fonts'));
});
```

App > Build > Fonts >

Bootstrap > Fonts > Font Files
Font-Awesome > Fonts > Font Files

**TL;DR**

Using my second method is copying the files as shown above, copying over the package folder and moving that with a 'fonts' folder as a child. Could anyone help show me where I have gone wrong...

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party here, but for anyone that stumbles upon this in the future: I believe you have a typo in your font glob: **eof** should be **eot**.

```
gulp.src('./bower_components/**/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}')
```

should be

```
gulp.src('./bower_components/**/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eot,svg}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best idea to always rely that a package will keep fonts in specific folders, those things can change.

Possibly you're missing another `/**/` before fonts (one folder level). Or why all those checks, you know what extensions fonts will have, perhaps add wildcard like `**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}`

Have you ever tried managing it with gulp-main-bower-files? https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files

Answer (score 0):

you can test this task 
i worked by it

```
gulp.task('copyfonts', () =>
gulp.src('./app/assets/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/assets/fonts'))
```

);

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue. After running my gulp builds, my fonts never successfully copied to my dest/fonts folder. The issue was inside my gulp.js file on these lines:

```
function fonts() {
  return src('app/fonts/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}')
    .pipe($.if(!isProd, dest('.tmp/fonts'), dest('dist/fonts')));
};
```

After editing the last line, my fonts successfully copied over!

```
function fonts() {
  return src('app/fonts/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}')
    .pipe(dest('dist/fonts'));
};
```